# How to set the user for the AWS CLI

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cli

After installing awscli (the AWS command line tool), when I try to run it. I get this message in the terminal:

```
        $ aws dynamodb describe-table --table-name MyTable

        An error occurred (AccessDeniedException) when calling the DescribeTable operation: 
    User: arn:aws:iam::213352837455:user/someuser is not authorized to
 perform: dynamodb:DescribeTable on resource: arn:aws:dynamodb:ap-northeast-1:213352837455:table/MyTable
        $
```

But I don't know why I am considered logged as someuser at this moment (in the terminal in particular, but even in AWS).
someuser is only one of the few users I have set on AWS, a while ago.

What is the way to get logged in as the right user, to use awscli?

Comment: You're never "logged in" when using the awscli. Every awscli invocation is independent of the previous one and, every time, the awscli retrieves credentials from the environment in which you are running awscli. See https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/userguide/cli-chap-getting-started.html

Comment: OK. What you write makes sense to me. Then why do I get this message?

Comment: Because you have credentials set in one of the places that the awscli looks for credentials. The awscli uses those credentials when you run it. And those credentials do not have permission to describe the DynamoDB table.

Comment: Things are becoming clearer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe your old credentials are still stored in `~/.aws`.

Log in with correct credentials

```
aws configure
```

For more info see [Configuring the AWS CLI](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/userguide/cli-chap-getting-started.html)
 in official documentation.

Comment: I just checked ~/.aws and nothing looks weird. Except that I am not sure that I filled the aws_access_key_id as I should have when running "aws configure". Where am I supposed to get this aws_access_key_id?
I may have used a wrong one.

Comment: @Michel The Access Key and Secret Key are generated for a user in the Identity and Access Management (IAM) console. See: [Managing Access Keys for IAM Users - AWS Identity and Access Management](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/id_credentials_access-keys.html)

Comment: OK, now it works. I created a user specially for the awscli, with permissions: AmazonDynamoDBFullAccess & AmazonS3FullAccess.
I hope it also follows best practices.

Answer (score 3):

If you are running the [AWS Command-Line Interface (CLI)](http://aws.amazon.com/cli/) on an Amazon EC2 instance that has been assigned a role, then the CLI can use the permissions associated with that role.

If you are not running on an EC2 instance, then you can provide credentials via a credentials file (`~/.aws/credentials`) or an environment variable.

The easiest way to configure the credentials is:

```
$ aws configure
```

See: [Configuring the AWS CLI](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/userguide/cli-chap-getting-started.html)